# Is cleaning a dog's floppy ears necessary?

Tags: dogs, bathing, cleaning

Me again. So my baby, Peanut, now a 14 month old female spayed Dachshund is growing into herself. I figure she's as big as she'll get, which is pretty darned small. (She's a miniature.) I've read that bathing your dog regularly (more than, say, once every couple months) is not recommended. We don't, and she really doesn't need it. She rarely smells 'dog-ish'.

- Knowing that, is it recommended to clean out her ears?
  A Dachshund is a 'floppy-eared' type.
- If it is so recommended, how often should we do it?
  I am currently cleaning them weekly, but they never seem to need it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Peanut (cute name) is an inside dog, which it sounds like she is, cleaning weekly isn't necessary. However - dirt, germs, etc can get in there at any time when she goes outside, and they could get musty and later infected of water gets in there when she's being bathed, and not properly dried (just examples so not at all insinuating that you wouldn't be thorough) so I would recommend at least checking her ears once a week and cleaning them when/if necessary

I hope this helps!
Liana

Comment: I agree with this answer. I just want to add that I have a dog with furry ears and furry/floppy ears don't have good air circulation. Any moisture that gets in them can cause a yeast/ear infection. My keeshond had this happen and scratched her ear so bad it caused a hematoma that needed surgery to fix. Over the years, these periodic ear infections have pretty much caused her to go deaf. So it's important to keep an eye on it, even if you don't clean them that often. They may not need frequent cleaning, though. It depends on the dog and their situation.